# Open source VOIP SDK in QT

Tags: qt, sdk, voip

I have a task to build a radio communication over IP using Qt ..

my question is :

1. can i use VOIP as communication protocol ?
2. is there any free SDK for VOIP in Qt ?

Answer (score 1):

Look into using [FreeSWITCH](http://www.freeswitch.org/) for this.